# Remove commits by email?

Tags: git, github

I want to remove all previous git commits for a certain email as I made commits with an incorrect email and have rectified it but now I have duplicate commits of everything, one with the correct email and one with the incorrect email. (root@jtp) I have tried:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "root@jtp" ];
    then
            skip_commit "$@";
    else
            git commit-tree "$@";
    fi' HEAD
```

and get this in return:

> fatal: ambiguous argument ' --commit-filter'
>       unknown revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate pathsfrom revisions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you entered `git filter-branch --commit-filter ...` and then `git filter-branch -f \ --commit-filter`. Which is it? While the first one might work, that bogus backslash `\` will definitely throw things off. Try removing it.

Comment: Tried and am now getting `"filename:needs merge"` on everything

Comment: Look at the message you get: `ambiguous argument ' --commit-filter'`. Do you see the space before `--`? This is because of your backslash. Your repository is in a weird state because of previous commands, reset it and run again (without the backslash).